# I can't load data from Database to display the results of the UIPickerView

Tags: json, swift

I can't load data from Database to display the results of the `UIPickerView`. I test by fix array value `UIPicker` can load data in to `pickerView`  but when I use array load json `UIPickerViewDataSource` cannot load into picker view

**can load**

```
var team = ["Apple", "Banana", "Tomato", "Corn", "Bean", "Orange", "Mango", "Mangoteen"]
```

**canot load**

```
var team: [AnyObject] = []
```

```
import UIKit

class getAllTeamViewController: UIViewController,UIPickerViewDataSource,UIPickerViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {

var selectValue: String?

@IBOutlet weak var showSelectValuePickerView: UITextField!

// Array
    //var team = ["Apple", "Banana", "Tomato", "Corn", "Bean", "Orange", "Mango", "Mangoteen"]
    var team: [AnyObject] = []

//Function getValue from database
func getvalue() -> Void {
    //get the values from sql/Json
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.test.com/myWebService/getteamPickView.php")

    let data = NSData(contentsOf: url! as URL)
    var jsonResponse = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data! as Data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! NSArray
        jsonResponse = jsonResponse.reversed() as NSArray
        reloadInputViews()
        print("jsonResponse ==> \(jsonResponse)")

    for candidate in jsonResponse {
        if let cdict = candidate as? NSDictionary {
            //fullName is the column name in sql/json
            let names = cdict["NameTeam"]
            self.selectValue?.append(((names! as AnyObject) as! String))
            print("Names ==> \(String(describing: names))")
        }//if
    }//for
}//getvalue

//  Picker View Function
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return self.team.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    let titleRow = (team[row] )
    return titleRow as? String
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    if team.count > 0 && team.count >= row{
        self.showSelectValuePickerView.text = self.team[row] as? String 
        self.showSelectValuePickerView.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, this is really bad code. There are so many bad practices.

- Don't declare an array as `[AnyObject]` if it's clearly `[String]`.
  This avoids horrible type cast like `names! as AnyObject) as! String`
- Don't use `NSData`, `NSURL`, `NSArray`, `NSDictionary` in Swift. Use native types.
- `.mutableContainers` is pointless in Swift, omit the entire parameter.
- **Never** load data synchronously from a remote URL with `Data(contentsOf`.
- Reload UI always on the main thread.
- Handle all errors! At least `print` them.

The error occurs because you call `reloadInputViews()` – which I assume reloads the picker view – before populating the data source array.

And rather than populating the data source array `team` you append the strings to `selectValue` which makes no sense.

This is a slightly optimized version of your code

```
@IBOutlet weak var showSelectValuePickerView: UITextField!

var team = [String]()

//Function getValue from database
func getvalue() {
    //get the values from sql/Json
    let url = URL(string: "http://www.test.com/myWebService/getteamPickView.php")!
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _ , error) in
        if let error = error { print(error); return }
        do {
            if let jsonResponse = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? [[String:Any]] {
                self.team = jsonResponse.compactMap{ $0["NameTeam"] as? String }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.reloadInputViews()
                }
            } else { print("JSON is not an array") }
        } catch { print(error) }
    }
    task.resume()
}

//  Picker View Function
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return self.team.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return team[row]
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    self.showSelectValuePickerView.text = self.team[row]
    self.showSelectValuePickerView.isHidden = true // Are you serious ??? This hides the text field
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm new iOS developers